# notepad++ to search a line for varied strings. advanced commands

Tags: notepad++, duplicate, string

here it is

```
ab12@zmial.com, Charles Dawson cd21@zmial.com, ef23@zmial.com, gh32@zmial.com,
ij34@zmial.com, mn45@zmial.com, op54@zmial.com, Queen Roffman qr56@zmial.com,
kl43@zmial.com, st65@zmial.com, za87@zmial.com, uv67@zmial.com, mn45@zmial.com,
Wanda Ximenes wx76@zmial.com, yz78@zmial.com,
```

I want to remove the strings before the 'emails' therefore only remains the 'emails at example dot example' seperated by comma.

Also, I want to search for any repeated or duplicated terms or words in all text.
What command for that purpose would reply me 'mn45@zmial.com' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part (I don't know how to report duplicates), assuming

- The document contains only the block you gave.
- The character "~" does not appear in the string (substitute a different unique character if it does).

  1. Select all the text with *Edit > Select All* (Ctrl+A).
  2. Join the lines into one with *Edit > Line Operations > Join Lines* (Ctrl+J).
  3. Mark emails by replacing regular expression `([^@\s]+@[^.\s]+\.[^,]+)` with `~\1,\n`.
  4. Delete strings before emails by replacing regular expression `.*~` with a null string.
  5. If it is no longer selected, select all the text with *Edit > Select All* (Ctrl+A).
  6. Join the lines into one with *Edit > Line Operations > Join Lines* (Ctrl+J).
  7. Manually remove any excess commas at the end.